# debug ghostscript error

Tags: ghostscript

I'm getting the following error when running ghostscript and converting a pdf file:

```
 GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 255
```

How do I begin to figure out what's wrong?

**Update:**
Here's my command:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=letter -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf -dPDFFitPage in.pdf
```

When I run it with png16 instead of pdfwrite, all goes well.  I'm assuming the issue is with the device, but still don't know how to fix that.  Goal here is to force the document to be letter-sized dimensions.

Link to the file: http://temp-share.com/show/FHKdql0i6/672b9ff65ff286352936d4e9975389bb

Comment: This would be a more useful question for others if you edit to add (a link to) the file to the question itself.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. It would be **better** *in* the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I've debugged this and its basically a limitation in the Ghostscript pdfwrite device. It only allows for a maximum of 10 nesting levels for objects (there's a fixed size stack declared), and the rather insane level of nesting in this Cairo file breaks that limit.

The obvious 'quick hack' of increasing the stack size by one does fix the problem, but clearly this isn't a long term solution, there's no guarantee that some other mad file won't nest beyond this level.

I'd suggest you open a bug report at http://bugs.ghostscript.com, flag the component as PDF Writer, which will make me the assignee. Fixing this properly is going to take more time than I have available right at the moment.

If you want to hack around the problem for now, and don't mind rebuilding Ghostscript, in ghostpdl/gs/base/gdevpdfx.h at around line 751 change:

pdf_viewer_state vgstack[11];

To:

pdf_viewer_state vgstack[12];

Answer (score 1):

Is that the entire output, or was there more ? That is not a PostScript error, so the error code is 'probably' a system error code from the OS.

Likely causes could be invalid permissions for creating the output file or reading the input file. NB the pdfwrite device (unlike the png16m device) needs to write temporary files, which it does using OS-specific methods for temporary files. If it can't write a temporary file that would cause an error. What happens if you run the process as root ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't think its a permissions issue.  The same exact command works for every other pdf I've tried.  Its this particular file that I'm working with is throwing this error.  I tried with sudo, that didn't help either.

Comment: Can you post (a link to) the offending input file ? Have you tried it on a different system ? Have you tried running as root ?

Comment: Here's the file: http://temp-share.com/show/FHKdql0i6/672b9ff65ff286352936d4e9975389bb  I have tried root, and a different system.  That didnt work.

Comment: Well the first step in debugging this is reduce the complexity of the input. This is a 9 page PDF file, and the error occurs on page 8. In addition its a hideously complicated Cairo PDF file. What appears to be the source of the problem is a Form which paints an area with a Pattern, which uses a Form, which paints its area with a Pattern, which uses a Form which calls another Form. All of which needlessly use transparency. The usual 'lets see how complicated and slow we can make this' Cairo-produced PDF file. You should go back to the original and make it simpler, then make a new PDF file.

Comment: In my experience that's typical of Cairo's pdf output.